# Tracking when the iframe embed code is used on other sites

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have videos on my site that can be embedded into other sites via an iframe embed code.

Let say the path being iframed is "mysite.com/embed/100"

Is there anyway for me to track and count how many times this iframe code has been embedded on other sites?

Is there anyway for me to get a list of which sites they have been embedded in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You can the best solution is **Google Tag Manager** and **Google Analytics**. You can configure them for `Tracking Cross-Domain Iframes`

Or

You can make your own tracker with pure PHP like this

```
<?php

echo "Requested_Page= " . $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "$

echo "<hr>";

echo "Requested_By= " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

?>
```

Remember `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` never be a good solution it can be spoof easily

And

For knowing how many times page in opened by a Domain you can run a Counter in backend in your DB

```
id  |  reqested_by  | requested_page  | requested_count
---- --------------- ----------------- ----------------
1   |  google.com   | mypage.php      |  45
```